# gazebo pioneer simulation = real robot behaviour?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to run some experiments on pioneer 3dx. Before porting on real bot, I want to run these in simulation environment. P2os stack do provide urdf model and an interface with gazebo. I can tele-operate this model with erratic_teleop package. Is it correct to say that real robot will have similar behaviour to robot model?

Can I use stage in conjuction with gazebo so that path planning can be done using maps in stage and execution of happen as with robot model?

nitin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29858/gazebo-pioneer-simulation-=-real-robot-behaviour-?/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, gazebo works on ODE & Ogre graphics engines and stage works on FLTK & OpenGL libraries.Further, gazebo models are made using xml scripts and stage models are world files. Hence, I do not think that gazebo and stage can be made work in tandem - they are rather different philosophies !

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-18**:
Ok, I got this, but what about p2os behaviour?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-18**:
@prince The real robot should have nearly the same behaviour as shown in simulations (depends on the correctness of the model, mechatronic functioning etc) however you have rolled up 2 questions into one - if I were you, I would have asked this as 2 separate questions.